# How to use SQL server 2005 with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I am trying to get ruby on rails to work with SQL server 2005 on the network from a windows 7 64-bit development machine.

I edited the database.yml:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlserver
  dsn: ODBC_SYSTEM_DSN
  username: admin
  password: ********
  host: 111.222.333.444
```

I completed this tutorial (well at least to the part where I am stuck now) and everything worked fine: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

One problem is the tutorial creates the batabase tables and I must use existing tables.

I created the following table for testing purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Emp_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Emp_Name] [nchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I ran these commands:

```
rails generate scaffold Employee
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

And it appeared all the stuff got created.  Sending the browser here:
http://localhost:3000/employees/new

Then I received this error:
No route matches [POST] "/employees/new"

Not sure whats going on since ruby explanations seem to be in short supply, I tried adding this to routes.rb:

```
post 'employees/show'
```

I got farther if that guess was right.  I even tried:

```
post 'employees/new'
```

Then I got this error (it seems it doesn't recognize the column name):
NoMethodError in Employees#new

From this code:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :ID %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :Emp_ID %>
</p>
```

I am trying to see if I can even see the database because just setting it up was a challenge without any clear instructions.  But it seems like it may not however not knowing how this is supposed to work is not helpful.  It seems every example I find does something different without any explanation.

Comment: The table needs to be named `employees` (plural). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not playing with scaffolding or routing until you can verify that Rails can talk to your DB, and that models are mapped correctly to the DB tables.

`rails console` is your friend. Use only the console and create your test models in `app/models`.

Rails table and column names are always lower case, so it would be good to stick to that format, at least until you can get something working.

Rails table names are also, unless otherwise specified, always plural of the model name. So in order to make a simple test case for your purposes you need to name your table `employees`, and your model name will be `Employee`.

Then run `rails console`, and simply type `Employee` at the prompt. If everything works correctly you should see the console write back the model name and column names to you.

After this simple test you can be more confident to continue to the next steps, since now you should know that the database connection is working properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I can not name the table Employees since an object already exists with that name.  I made a new table called "Cars" and also created a model.  I tried entering Cars at the prompt and it replied with "NameError: uninitialized constant Cars".  Does this mean the connection to the database is bad or is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: The model name should be singular, the table should be plural. So you need to create `class Car < ActiveRecord::Base`, and put that in `app/models/car.rb`.

Comment: I have done all that.  The table is plural.  The class is singular.  I get table does not exist.  I am going through another tutorial but I haven't found anything that explains what needs to be done to use SQL server 2005.  There are posts on this site but they all seem to be incomplete.